# "experiences aligns" or "experiences align"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> I'd like to share how my **experiences aligns** with your requirements.

Is that a correct sentence? Or is it supposed to be "experiences **align**"?

Comment: [Here are some tips](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question) for giving your next question an improved title.

Answer (score 1):

Here

> my experiences

are plural, so one should use

> (1) I'd like to share how my **experiences align**...

if you are referring to multiple experiences. However, "experience" as a singular can also be used to mean "all of the things I've done/learned" as in "work experience" or something similar, so one could also say:

> (2) I'd like to share how my **experience aligns**...

The first way, with multiple experiences, you are treating experiences as a series of episodes. In the second way, you are treating experience as a singular summed history.

Both are grammatically correct and logical, but given the rest of the context of the sentence I think it sounds most natural to use (2) if you are thinking about summed skills and knowledge related to a job. If, following this statement, you plan to discuss multiple individual experiences then (1) may fit better.